# Pegar informações de api com socket local

Tags: python, json

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um programa para processar mensagens do whatsapp e responde-las (chatbot) e para isso comprei um programa chamado zapmax, nele é detectado a mensagem e é enviada para o servidor via api com o method POST, então criei um servidor local com socket, porém não consigo receber as informações com este código recebo o seguinte no terminal:

```
def aceitar_conexao():
    while True:
        client = {}
        endereco, client = servidor.accept()
        msg = endereco.recv(1024)
        print(msg)
```

mensagem que aparece no terminal: **b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nHost: 10.1.1.124:7000\r\nContent-Length: 177\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n'**

então tentei fazer uma requisição assim:

```
def aceitar_conexao():
    while True:
        client = {}
        endereco, client = servidor.accept()
        ht = 'https://10.1.1.124:' + str(client[1])
        mnsg = '\"{}\"'.format(ht)
        request = requests.get(ht)
        print(request)
```

e desta forma não acontece nada além de fechar o terminal, se alguem conseguir me dar uma luz, serei eternamente agradecido, ainda sou desenvolvedor júnior então não tenho muita experiência com isso, irei deixar tbm uma imagem que o suporte me mandou contendo as informações enviadas pelo programa:
[image: Informações passada pelo method POST]

Comment: acho que é por requisição get e post e não via socket

Answer (score -1):

Não use sockets, use algum módulo que implemente um servidor HTTP de verdade, tipo o SimpleHTTPServer (Python 2.x) ou http.server (Python 3.x).